# Sitecore 8.1 MVC Areas views integration from Global project to multiple website

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore-mvc, sitecore8.1

I am planning to integrate following Visual studio project with Sitecore instance:

**Sample.SC.Global ( MVC project )**  --This project contains global/common implementation which will be used in Website1/Website2 for example Global Global/Footer Header(GlobalHeader.cshtml,GlobalFooter.cshtml in Area folder structure ) and I am using Areas in this MVC project

**Sample.SC.Helper ( C# class library)** --This will work as helper class library

**Sample.SC.Website1 ( MVC project )** --This project contains Views specific to this website and use Global Header/Footer from Sample.SC.Global project

**Sample.SC.Website2 ( MVC project )** --This project contains Views specific to this website and use Global Header/Footer from Sample.SC.Global project

Queries:

1.How to reference GlobalHeader.cshtml and GlobalFooter.cshtml in Website1 so that when I browse Website Global Header/Footer must display with views  specific to **Website1/Website2**

2.In Sitecore GlobalHeader/GlobalFooter view rendering item **Path** field should I have to enter the path of these files from **Sample.SC.Global** MVC project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can accomplish this without creating 3 website projects. You can achieve it with 1 web project. Since you are using Areas, you can break out each "child site" into a new area.

For example this is what Visual Studio would look like
-Sample.Website

-

- Global
- Header
- Footer
- - Areas
  - Site1

    - Controllers
    - Views
  - Site2

    - Controllers
    - Views

In Sitecore, you would create 2 separate sites and a separate folder for your shared items. Remember that the only items that go under your Site/Home should be pages. Any other items should be in a Folder name Components or MetaData or something similar to that.